# python, while loop, p values

Tags: python, mongodb, while-loop

I am having trouble debugging this program which calculates the p values for a number of tweets:

```
db = connection.data
shows = db.individual

def pvalue():
    #p-values of total tweets
    show_records = sorted([(m['total_tweets'], m) for m in db.individual.find()])

    index=0
    while index < len(show_records):    
         show = show_records[index]
        tweet_pvalue = 1 - (index + 1.0) / len(show_records)
        total=show['total_tweets']
        shows.update({"id": show[1]["id"]}, {'$set':{"pvalue_total_tweets":tweet_pvalue}})

    #need to remove several occurences of the same number of tweets to not false the p-value. 

        while show_records[index + 1]['total_tweets'] == total: #while next document has the same number of tweets
            index+=1
            show=show_records[index]
            shows.update({"id": show[1]["id"]}, {'$set':{"pvalue_total_tweets":tweet_pvalue}})
```

It returns:

```
total=show['total_tweets']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You seem to think that `show` is a dictionary, but it's not, it's a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show_records = sorted([(m['total_tweets'], m) for m in db.individual.find()])
```

This returns a list of tuples like `[(1, {'total_tweets': 1}), (2, {'total_tweets': 2}]`.

And this one

```
show = show_records[index]
```

returns (for example if index == 1) - `(2, {'total_tweets': 2})`, which is tuple. And you are trying to do

```
(2, {'total_tweets': 2})['total_tweets']
```

and it causes an error. You should write:

```
(2, {'total_tweets': 2})[1]['total_tweets']
```